# Missing parameter

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm having trouble to pass the version parameter in a POST request using GuzzleHttp.

Client error: `GET https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"code":400,"sub_code":"C00005","error":"Missing a minor version parameter in the URL. To use the latest version, add th (truncated...)

This is the latest I've tried:

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/'
    ]);
    $toneAnalyserResponse = $client->request('POST', 'tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone', [
        'auth' => ['{username}', '{password}'],
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'version' => '2017-09-21',
            'tone_input' => $text,
            'sentences' => true
        ]
    ]);
```

This was failing too:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/'
]);
$toneAnalyserResponse = $client->request('POST', 'tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone', [
    'auth' => ['{username}', '{password}'],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
    ],
    'version' => '2017-09-21',
    'tone_input' => $text,
    'sentences' => true
]);
```

Failing as well if using GET instead of POST.

If I change the URI and add the version, then it works fine (well, it fails as it doesn't have the text to analyse in the request):

Change: tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone

To: tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21

So, I guess the question is HOW DO YOU PASS URL PARAMETERS in a request using GuzzleHttp?

Note: my CURL command works fine (http 200):

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Language: en' --header 'Accept-Language: en' -d 'I hate these new features On #ThisPhone after the update.\r\n \ 
     I hate #ThisPhoneCompany products, you%27d have to torture me to get me to use #ThisPhone.\r\n \ 
     The emojis in #ThisPhone are stupid.\r\n \ 
     #ThisPhone is a useless, stupid waste of money.\r\n \ 
     #ThisPhone is the worst phone I%27ve ever had - ever .\r\n \ 
     #ThisPhone another ripoff, lost all respect SHAME.\r\n \ 
     I%27m worried my #ThisPhone is going to overheat like my brother%27s did.\r\n \ 
     #ThisPhoneCompany really let me down... my new phone won%27t even turn on.' 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&sentences=true'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to send "query" parameter for querystring. Pleaes check the below codes:

```
$toneAnalyserResponse = $client->request('POST', 'tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone', [
    'auth' => ['{username}', '{password}'],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
    ],
    'query' => [
       'version' => '2017-09-21'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have less than 15 reputations so can't give you a 'high five'.